# add values of 5 text boxes and show the esult in 6th tetbo on the keypress vent of 5 th textbox

Tags: javascript

i have 6 text boxes with id a,b,c,d,e,f.out of these i enter value for 5.i

want to get result like a+b+max(c,d,e) in 6th text box on the keypress event

of 5 th textbox.

i write code in javascipt but it doesnt work

```js
function max_sum() {
    var p = document.getElementById('p').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var m = document.getElementById('m').value;
    var cs = document.getElementById('cs').value;
    var s = Math.max(b,m,cs);

    var total = parseInt(p) + parseInt(c)+ parseInt(s)

    if (!isNaN(total)) {
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
}
```

i call my function here

```
<td width="69" style="text-align: center" colspan="1">
    <input name="cs" type="text" class="txtm" id="cs" size="6" required="required" onkeypress="return MoveNext('total', event.keyCode);,max_sum();"/>
</td>
```

Comment: does not relate to php or mysql

Comment: i am caling this javascript function in php and saving into database using mysql

Comment: _"it doesnt work"_ doesnt help explain the problem. What is happening that shouldnt, or not happening but should? Have you checked the javascript console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you JS console contains `Uncaught ReferenceError: max_sum is not defined`.

Assign your `max_sum` function to global variable:

```
window.max_sum = function() {
   //...
}
```